# Docker compose environment variables missing on reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Setup**

I have a docker-compose setup (file version 3.7) where I bind volumes with

```
volumes:
  - ${VOLUME_DIR}/media:/media
restart: unless-stopped
```

including the restart policy.

Before I run `docker-compose up`, I set `export VOLUME_DIR=$HOME/volumes`,
where my media folder is located.
I.e. it is resolved during `docker-compose up` to locate the media folder in `$HOME/volumes/media`.

I start it from a non-root user and it runs perfectly.

**Problem**

Once I reboot the machine, everything is restarted from root and it tries to locate the media folder in `/root/volumes/media`.

Why does that happen? Doesn't it just use the "final" compose file as you can see it by running `docker-compose config`? How do I solve this?

Edit: Just to clarify, I don't run `docker-compose up` a second time, I run it once with the ENV variables set and want to rely on the restart policy to restart it exactly the way I started it initially when it crashes/the system reboots.

**First solution:**

Thanks to Exadra37's and camba1's comments, I could at least get it running by creating a .env file on startup to "dump" my current ENV variables which I need there.

But I still don't understand to which degree information is being kept for docker-compose's restart policy, so why the ENV variable which could have been hard-baked when running `docker-compose up` is disregarded.

Comment: Did you permanently set the value of the VOLUME_DIR in your .bash_profile? Otherwise you need to re-export the variable every time your restart your shell.

Comment: No, I do not.
But I think that has nothing to do with the question because I only run `docker-compose up` once, I'm asking for the auto restart on boot.
Furthermore, as I said, after reboot it tries to locate it in `/root`, which means the restart mechanism would not even run it from the original user.

Comment: The auto restart will not run as your user. I would recommend to either put the actual to the directory or create a .env file where you can store the value. I would not rely on $HOME

Comment: But `export VOLUME_DIR=$HOME/volumes` is expanded on assignment, so `VOLUME_DIR=/home/myuser/volumes`, which is then applied to the docker-compose file. When I run `docker-compose config` the value is actually inserted and shows `- /home/myuser/volumes/media:/media` for the volume.
But I don't find any docs explaning if what can be seen with `docker-compose config` is what is actually stored for restarting

Answer (score 0):

> Why does that happen?

It will happen without reboot the server, you just need to exit the shell and get back to it again to loose your `export ...`, because export it's temporary and only lasts for that shell session.

> Doesn't it just use the "final" compose file as you can see it by running docker-compose config?

Because the file is parsed when you run the docker compose command, and if the `VOLUME_DIR` is not set for the current bash session environment, then docker compose will fail to evaluate it. You can solve it by giving it a default value:

```
volumes:
  - ${VOLUME_DIR:-/default/path/here}/media:/media
restart: unless-stopped
```

Bear in mind that to use the bash variable expansion you need to use docker compose versions `2.1` or above.

> How do I solve this?

Just create a `.env` file in the same folder where your `docker-compose.yml` is located:

```
VOLUME_DIR=/path/to/volume/here
```

Comment: I edited my original post and added that I'm using version 3.7, furthermore:
Just to clarify, I don't run `docker-compose up` a second time, I run it once with the ENV variables set and want to rely on the restart policy to restart it exactly the way I started it initially when it crashed/rebooted.

Of course, if I start it manually after a reboot or even restarting the bash, the ENV var would be gone. But I would expect docker-compse to store the exact docker-compose file with the inserted ENV variables to know how to restart when the restart policy applies.